# Ruby encoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, rubymine

I am saving a CSV file from the web. On the web it appears encoded correctly, but when I save it inside a folder in my app I see that the character "µ" is missing and a "�" appears in its place.

The page where I get the data does not have an encoding in the header, anyway I specify the reading encoding in my code (a rake task) which is the following:

```
open("public/test.csv", "w:UTF-8") do |file|
  open("http://url.CSV", "r:UTF-8") do |row|
    file.write(row.read)
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am using RubyMine by the way.

Comment: How do you know the encoding of the original file is utf-8?

Comment: Don't you think an actual URL would be easier?

Comment: How are you viewing the web file when you see `µ` vs the local file when you see the `?` (and is it a normal ASCII question mark or perhaps a question mark with diamond background)?

Comment: @Neil Slater 
The file looks identical to the web except fot the question mark and yes, it has a diamond background!

Comment: The default character encoding for HTTP is ISO-8859-1

Comment: Under Response Header there are only:
CONNECTION
DATE
ETAG
KEEPALIVE
SERVER

Comment: @Jack: By "how are you viewing" I meant "which software are you using to view". I was wondering about possible support in the viewing software. However, I think Slicedpan is onto likely correct reason for your problem. Try ISO-8859-1 encoding for the inner, read block.

Comment: I recently had a similar issue with a CSV file. I used the free utility 'TextWrangler' (quite a nice text editor with syntax highlighting), which detects input text format and allows you to save in whichever format you desire. UTF8 seemed to work nicely with Rubymine.

http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/

Sadly it's Mac only, but I'm sure similar utilities exist for other formats. I hear Notepad++ is good for the PC.

Comment: Thank you, ISO-8859-1 was the solution!
How can I give you the answer Slicedpan?

Comment: I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default encoding for HTTP is ISO-8859-1. The saved CSV file used that encoding, so when reading it in Ruby, you must set the encoding correctly:

```
File.open('filename.csv', 'r:ISO-8859-1') do |f|
  # do something with the contents
end
```